# Gekko Exception: @error: Solution Not Found

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I am trying to optimize the time point at which it is best to start the device so that it would reduce the power bill. I formulated the problem as an INLP.

```
df = pd.read_csv('hourly.csv')
power_balance= df["house_connection"].to_numpy() #Measurements of house connection. Can be both positive and negative
    
df = pd.read_csv('device_hourly.csv')
device_profile= df["device"].to_numpy() #Measurement of device power profile
    
N = power_balance.size 
l = device_profile.size # l<N in all cases
    
priceBuy = 0.23 # Euro/kWh
priceSell = 0.063 # Euro/kWh
    
m = GEKKO(remote=False) 
m.options.SOLVER=1 
    
# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 1000', \
                   # minlp iterations with integer solution
                   'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 1000', \
                   # treat minlp as nlp
                   'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                   # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                   'nlp_maximum_iterations 1000', \
                   # maximum deviation from whole number
                   'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                   # covergence tolerance
                   'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']
    
# Initialize variables
is_start = m.Array(m.Var,N,integer=True, lb=0, ub=1) #Vector of binary controls. 
    
    
E_spent = m.Array(m.Var,N) # Amount of energy that is bought from grid
E_gain = m.Array(m.Var,N) # Amount of energy that is sold back to grid
    
m.Equation(sum(is_start)==1) # only one time point can be True as start of device
m.Equations([is_start[i] == 0 for i in range(N-l,N)]) # you cannot start the device at the end of time period
    
# Special case, start time is qual to 0.
m.Equation(E_spent[0]==m.max2(0, power_balance[0]+is_start[0]*device_profile[0])) # Excess of consumption, energy must be bought from grid
m.Equation(E_gain[0]==m.min2(0,power_balance[0]+is_start[0]*device_profile[0])) # Excess of production, energy can be sold from grid
    
# For all time points in case amounts of energy equal to power balance and part of device profile. 
# It can be, that start time happened before, so we take second point of device profile insted of first
    m.Equations([E_spent[i]==m.max2(0,power_balance[i]+is_start[i]*device_profile[0]+is_start[i-1]*device_profile[1]) for i in range(2,N)])
    m.Equations([E_gain[i]==m.min2(0,power_balance[i]+is_start[i]*device_profile[0]+is_start[i-1]*device_profile[1]) for i in range(2,N)])
    
# Minimize amount of money spent on energy
m.Minimize(np.sum([E_spent[i]*priceBuy+E_gain[i]*priceSell for i in range(N)])) 

m.solve(disp=True)
    
print('Results')  
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

As a result, I get the error @error: Solution Not Found and it seems like there is infeasibility if I use max/min functions in my constraints. Is there a nice way how to fix it or reformulate it to be more suitable for GEKKO?

Answer (score 0):

The original script doesn't run because it is missing the input files. Below is a complete version of the problem that reproduces the unsuccessful solution:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

#df = pd.read_csv('hourly.csv')
#Measurements of house connection. Can be both positive and negative
power_balance= np.array([1,1,0,-1,-1])
    
#df = pd.read_csv('device_hourly.csv')
#Measurement of device power profile
device_profile= np.array([0.1,0.1,0.12]) 

N = power_balance.size 
l = device_profile.size # l<N in all cases
    
priceBuy = 0.23 # Euro/kWh
priceSell = 0.063 # Euro/kWh
    
m = GEKKO(remote=False) 
m.options.SOLVER=1 
    
# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 1000', \
                   # minlp iterations with integer solution
                   'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 1000', \
                   # treat minlp as nlp
                   'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                   # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                   'nlp_maximum_iterations 1000', \
                   # maximum deviation from whole number
                   'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                   # covergence tolerance
                   'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']
    
# Initialize variables
is_start = m.Array(m.Var,N,integer=True, lb=0, ub=1) #Vector of binary controls. 
    
    
E_spent = m.Array(m.Var,N) # Amount of energy that is bought from grid
E_gain = m.Array(m.Var,N) # Amount of energy that is sold back to grid
    
m.Equation(sum(is_start)==1) # only one time point can be True as start of device
m.Equations([is_start[i] == 0 for i in range(N-l,N)]) # you cannot start the device at the end of time period
    
# Special case, start time is qual to 0.
m.Equation(E_spent[0]==m.max2(0, power_balance[0]+is_start[0]*device_profile[0])) # Excess of consumption, energy must be bought from grid
m.Equation(E_gain[0]==m.min2(0,power_balance[0]+is_start[0]*device_profile[0])) # Excess of production, energy can be sold from grid
    
# For all time points in case amounts of energy equal to power balance and part of device profile. 
# It can be, that start time happened before, so we take second point of device profile insted of first
m.Equations([E_spent[i]==m.max2(0,power_balance[i]+is_start[i]*device_profile[0]+is_start[i-1]*device_profile[1]) for i in range(2,N)])
m.Equations([E_gain[i]==m.min2(0,power_balance[i]+is_start[i]*device_profile[0]+is_start[i-1]*device_profile[1]) for i in range(2,N)])
    
# Minimize amount of money spent on energy
m.Minimize(np.sum([E_spent[i]*priceBuy+E_gain[i]*priceSell for i in range(N)])) 

m.solve(disp=True)
    
print('Results')  
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

I encourage you to change from `max2()` to `max3()` and from `min2()` to `min3()` as a common strategy to improve convergence. Successful solution is achieved by removing the minimum and maximum conditions on the first time point.

```py
# Special case, start time is qual to 0.
m.Equation(E_spent[0]==power_balance[0]+is_start[0]*device_profile[0]) # Excess of consumption, energy must be bought from grid
m.Equation(E_gain[0]==power_balance[0]+is_start[0]*device_profile[0]) # Excess of production, energy can be sold from grid
```

Hopefully this gives some insight on why the problem becomes infeasible without the modification.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

#df = pd.read_csv('hourly.csv')
#Measurements of house connection. Can be both positive and negative
power_balance= np.array([1,1,0,-1,-1])
    
#df = pd.read_csv('device_hourly.csv')
#Measurement of device power profile
device_profile= np.array([0.1,0.1,0.12]) 

N = power_balance.size 
l = device_profile.size # l<N in all cases
    
priceBuy = 0.23 # Euro/kWh
priceSell = 0.063 # Euro/kWh
    
m = GEKKO(remote=False) 
m.options.SOLVER=1 
    
# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 1000', \
                   # minlp iterations with integer solution
                   'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 1000', \
                   # treat minlp as nlp
                   'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                   # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                   'nlp_maximum_iterations 1000', \
                   # maximum deviation from whole number
                   'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                   # covergence tolerance
                   'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']
    
# Initialize variables
is_start = m.Array(m.Var,N,integer=True, lb=0, ub=1) #Vector of binary controls. 
    
    
E_spent = m.Array(m.Var,N) # Amount of energy that is bought from grid
E_gain = m.Array(m.Var,N) # Amount of energy that is sold back to grid
    
m.Equation(sum(is_start)==1) # only one time point can be True as start of device
m.Equations([is_start[i] == 0 for i in range(N-l,N)]) # you cannot start the device at the end of time period
    
# Special case, start time is qual to 0.
m.Equation(E_spent[0]==power_balance[0]+is_start[0]*device_profile[0]) # Excess of consumption, energy must be bought from grid
m.Equation(E_gain[0]==power_balance[0]+is_start[0]*device_profile[0]) # Excess of production, energy can be sold from grid
    
# For all time points in case amounts of energy equal to power balance and part of device profile. 
# It can be, that start time happened before, so we take second point of device profile insted of first
m.Equations([E_spent[i]==m.max3(0,power_balance[i]+is_start[i]*device_profile[0]+is_start[i-1]*device_profile[1]) for i in range(2,N)])
m.Equations([E_gain[i]==m.min3(0,power_balance[i]+is_start[i]*device_profile[0]+is_start[i-1]*device_profile[1]) for i in range(2,N)])
    
# Minimize amount of money spent on energy
m.Minimize(np.sum([E_spent[i]*priceBuy+E_gain[i]*priceSell for i in range(N)])) 

m.solve(disp=True)
    
print('Results')  
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

Another more efficient strategy for this type of problem is to use slack variables instead of binary variables for the switching behavior. Please see [Benchmark IV](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EnergyBenchmarks) from the Dynamic Optimization course and this [paper](https://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/Gates_2021.pdf).

> Gates, N.S., Hill, D.C., Billings, B.W., Powell, K.M., Hedengren, J.D., Benchmarks for Grid Energy Management with Python Gekko, 60th IEEE Conference on Decision and Control (CDC), Tutorial Session: Open Source Software for Control Applications, Austin, TX, Dec 13-15, 2021.

Comment: Thanks for your input. it doesn't make any change for me if I add max3/min3. I can provide my input data if it would help

Comment: `power_balance= np.array([1016.8348, 992.9000, 978.753, 973.619, 1032.473, 1177.838, 1166.2109,947.30, 255.51,188.86, -215.0951, -769.84327, -948.540, -733.72, -914.787, -574.685, -35.176, 156.57, 510.999, 877.450, 1095.850, 1100.7517, 1036.495, 948.146])`   and `device_profile=np.array([878.7496, 39.3974])`